# Sabre - PASSENGER TYPE FUNCTION INACTIVE IN TJR

Tags: api, soap

This is my request and response. After `EnhancedAirBookRQ`, I am trying to create `PassengerDetailsRQ`, but the below error is occurring in my response data.

`Err: <Message code="ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE">.PASSENGER TYPE FUNCTION INACTIVE IN TJR</Message>.`

Kindly help me on this.

```
**Request**:

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sec="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:mes="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" xmlns:v3="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_2">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <sec:Security>
         <sec:BinarySecurityToken>${#Project#SOAPSecurityToken}</sec:BinarySecurityToken>
      </sec:Security>
      <mes:MessageHeader mes:id="?" mes:version="?">
         <mes:From>
            <mes:PartyId mes:type="?">1212</mes:PartyId>
         </mes:From>
         <mes:To>
            <mes:PartyId mes:type="?">2323</mes:PartyId>
         </mes:To>
         <mes:CPAId>${#Project#Organization}</mes:CPAId>
         <mes:ConversationId>${#Project#ConversationID}</mes:ConversationId>
         <mes:Service mes:type="Sabre">PassengerDetailsRQ</mes:Service>
         <mes:Action>PassengerDetailsRQ</mes:Action>
         <mes:MessageData>
            <mes:MessageId>1001</mes:MessageId>
            <mes:Timestamp>2012-06-07T10:00:01</mes:Timestamp>
            <mes:TimeToLive>2013-06-06T23:59:59</mes:TimeToLive>
         </mes:MessageData>
      </mes:MessageHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v3:PassengerDetailsRQ version="3.2.0" HaltOnError="true" IgnoreOnError="true">
         <v3:PostProcessing IgnoreAfter="false" RedisplayReservation="true">
            <v3:EndTransactionRQ>
               <v3:EndTransaction Ind="true"/>
               <v3:Source ReceivedFrom="TEST"/>
            </v3:EndTransactionRQ>
         </v3:PostProcessing>
         <v3:PriceQuoteInfo>
            <v3:Link NameNumber="1.1" Record="1"/>
         </v3:PriceQuoteInfo>
         <v3:SpecialReqDetails>
            <v3:SpecialServiceRQ>
               <v3:SpecialServiceInfo>
                  <v3:AdvancePassenger SegmentNumber="A">
                     <v3:Document ExpirationDate="2025-05-26" Number="1234567890" Type="ADT">
                        <v3:IssueCountry>US</v3:IssueCountry>
                        <v3:NationalityCountry>US</v3:NationalityCountry>
                     </v3:Document>
                     <v3:PersonName DateOfBirth="1990-01-18" DocumentHolder="true" Gender="M" NameNumber="1.1">
                        <v3:GivenName>NISHANT</v3:GivenName>
                        <v3:Surname>SINGH</v3:Surname>
                     </v3:PersonName>
                  </v3:AdvancePassenger>
                  <v3:SecureFlight SegmentNumber="A">
                     <v3:PersonName DateOfBirth="1990-01-18" Gender="M" NameNumber="1.1">
                        <v3:GivenName>NISHANT</v3:GivenName>
                        <v3:Surname>SINGH</v3:Surname>
                     </v3:PersonName>
                  </v3:SecureFlight>
               </v3:SpecialServiceInfo>
            </v3:SpecialServiceRQ>
         </v3:SpecialReqDetails>
         <v3:TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ>
            <v3:AgencyInfo>
               <v3:Address>
                  <v3:AddressLine>SABRE TRAVEL</v3:AddressLine>
                  <v3:CityName>SOUTHLAKE</v3:CityName>
                  <v3:CountryCode>US</v3:CountryCode>
                  <v3:PostalCode>76092</v3:PostalCode>
                  <v3:StateCountyProv StateCode="TX"/>
                  <v3:StreetNmbr>3150 SABRE DRIVE</v3:StreetNmbr>
               </v3:Address>
               <v3:Ticketing TicketType="7T-"/>
            </v3:AgencyInfo>
            <v3:CustomerInfo>
               <v3:ContactNumbers>
                  <v3:ContactNumber Phone="817-555-1212" PhoneUseType="A"/>
                  <v3:ContactNumber Phone="972-555-1212" PhoneUseType="H"/>
               </v3:ContactNumbers>
               <v3:Email Address="testmail@sabre.com" NameNumber="1.1" ShortText="ABC123" Type="CC"/>
               <v3:PersonName NameNumber="1.1" PassengerType="ADT">
                  <v3:GivenName>BEAR</v3:GivenName>
                  <v3:Surname>TEST</v3:Surname>
               </v3:PersonName>
            </v3:CustomerInfo>
         </v3:TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ>
      </v3:PassengerDetailsRQ>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

**Response**:

<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap-env:Header>
      <eb:MessageHeader eb:version="1.0" soap-env:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader">
         <eb:From>
            <eb:PartyId eb:type="?">2323</eb:PartyId>
         </eb:From>
         <eb:To>
            <eb:PartyId eb:type="?">1212</eb:PartyId>
         </eb:To>
         <eb:CPAId>VJ6I</eb:CPAId>
         <eb:ConversationId>SWS-Test-VJ6I</eb:ConversationId>
         <eb:Service eb:type="Sabre">PassengerDetailsRQ</eb:Service>
         <eb:Action>PassengerDetailsRS</eb:Action>
         <eb:MessageData>
            <eb:MessageId>1ge244ppd</eb:MessageId>
            <eb:Timestamp>2017-07-11T05:33:47</eb:Timestamp>
            <eb:RefToMessageId>1001</eb:RefToMessageId>
         </eb:MessageData>
      </eb:MessageHeader>
      <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
         <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/ACPCRTC!ICESMSLB\/CRT.LB!-3255744940058014835!804634!0</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soap-env:Header>
   <soap-env:Body>
      <PassengerDetailsRS xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_2">
         <ApplicationResults status="NotProcessed" xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/STL_Payload/v02_01">
            <Error type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2017-07-11T00:33:47.320-05:00">
               <SystemSpecificResults>
                  <Message code="ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE">.PASSENGER TYPE FUNCTION INACTIVE IN TJR</Message>
               </SystemSpecificResults>
            </Error>
         </ApplicationResults>
      </PassengerDetailsRS>
   </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to Sabre possible errors this is a configuration issue on the PCC:

> This response occurs when you attempt to store a passenger type code
>   in the PNR and you do not have the "Store Passenger Type In PNR"
>   active in your PCC/TJR.
>
> Most likely you are performing a transaction in brand new PCC where
>   this setting has not been enabled.

The proposed solution in their site states:

> 1. If representatives from your organization have access to perform PCC/TJR updates, contact them to perform a W/PT‡ON activation on the
>      used PCC.
> 2. If your organization does not have access to perform PCC/TJR updates, contact your Sabre account team.

Good luck!